# dir-paginate with two dir-pagination-control

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

at the moment I have list of events with a pagination on the bottom of the list. That works well, but now I want to add a addintional pagination on the to of the list. When I now change the pagination on the bottom the pagination on the top is not updated.

My working code is:

```
<tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="event in events | orderBy:['id', 't']:true | itemsPerPage: dirPaginate.pageSize" current-page="dirPaginate.currentPage">

            <td><i class="{{ ::(event.el | eventtype).icon }}" tooltip="{{ ::(event.el | eventtype).tooltip }}"></i></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{::event.nr}}</td>
            <td><span ng-bind-html="::('' + event.tg | eventMessage:event.d:'html')"></span>
                <span class="visible-xs"> ({{::event.nr}})</span>
            </td>
            <td>{{ ::(event.t * 1000 | date:'mediumDate')}} <span class="visible-xs">{{ ::(event.t * 1000 | date:'mediumTime')}}</span></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{ ::(event.t * 1000 | date:'mediumTime')}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="paginationContainer"><dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
```

How can I uptate both paginations when one of them is changed?

Comment: I might be missing something but in your code I only see one dir-pagination-controls. Could you update this example in case you still want an answer? In case you have found an answer it might be good if you post your solution

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [dirPagination.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js) from here. .
2. Now include dirPagination.js to your page.
3. Add angularUtils.directives.dirPagination in your module like this

> var app = angular.module("myApp",
>   ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

```
4.we use dir-paginate directive for pagination  add dir-paginate in tr tag
```

> ```
> <tr dir-paginate="event in events|orderBy:['id', 't']:true |
>      itemsPerPage: dirPaginate.pageSize">
> ```

```
5.Add below given code on upper and lower side of your grid .it will automatically update page no. in both pagination controls. 


 <dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="5"
            direction-links="true"
            boundary-links="true" >
        </dir-pagination-controls>
```